# PHP - How to assign object variables to function variables automatically?

Tags: php

Below is a fragment of one of my functions, but I figured this seemed redundant and thus wanted to avoid it.

```
 function cellMaker($cell){
        $label= $cell['label'];
        $type= $cell['type'];
        $return= $cell['return'];
        $size= $cell['size'];
        $name= $cell['name'];
        $value= $cell['value'];
         ........
```

The reason I am doing this is to avoid having to fill in nulls with the function if I only need to pass two of the parameters, like just label and type and value. That would look like `cellMaker('how?', 'text' null, null, null, 'because');`

Rather I only would need to do `cellMaker(["label" => "how?", "type"=> "text", "value" => "because"])` which saves me from having to remember the order the variables are defined in the function and from having to deal with unnecessary variables. However I also do not want to have to type `$cell['variable']` rather than `$variable` each time.

Is there a way to automatically assign  all variables of an object to function variables of the same name?

Comment: I don't think I got what you are trying to achieve.
But take a look at [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

Comment: That is perfect, post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Though `extract` function is the right answer. I would not advise you to use it as you'll end up with bunch of variable that just appeared from nowhere. That would make debugging and support pain.

Comment: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: You may pass objects. That way you will be sure what kind of properties it may contain.

Comment: What is wrong with using `$cell['label']` as is?

Comment: Many  more characters and ugly in my opinion.

Comment: `extract` is almost always ugly anyway =)

Comment: Ugly, that is just taste/habit.  More characters :) lol, you'll save more on maintainability.

Comment: How is it ugly? It is a one line very quick function call.

Comment: OK so pretty much the answer here is don't. Unless say you already have a really long function defined that you want to switch over to using an object instead of variables. But you shouldn't have long functions anyways.

Comment: @JasonBasanese Your code, do what you want. You got an answer. Just accept it. People gave you warning that it is a bad idea, that is it.

Comment: If it matters, I ended up going with E_p's advice. Using the object directly is verbose but more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to get separate variables from an array.

```
$array = ["label" => "how?", "type"=> "text", "value" => "because"];
extract($array);
```

This will give you three variables named after keys in the array containing corresponding values.
Be warned though. It may become rather unpredictable. You wouldn't know for sure what kind of keys there may be in the input array.

Comment: But actually extract function may become pretty unpredictable.

Comment: I would put that warning in big letters in the answer itself

Comment: How can it become unpredicatable?

Comment: You can actually pass any kind of array there. With any kind of keys from some other part of your code base. If you use objects you will be sure about the properties it contains.
And it will actually save you some memory because PHP creates another array every time you pass it to a function. And with the object you will only send a reference to it.

Comment: @JasonBasanese Well, one thing if you had variable with same name right before you call `extract` you going to loose it.